# Anomalous merge conflict from diff ordering discrepancy?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I have an anomalous merge conflict in Git.  This was a test merge I never intended to keep anyway, but I want to understand *why* Git reports it as a conflict.

I have used a hex editor to take the SHA-1 hash of the affected file on both sides of the merge, and confirmed from this that the file is **bytewise identical** on both sides of the merge from *at least* 7 lines prior to, and through to *at least* 28 lines after, the supposed conflict.  This means that in reality there is no conflict and that it cannot be a matter of whitespace, line endings, strange Unicode normalizations, or non-displaying characters.

The conflict looks exactly like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD



#### Where To Put Untracked Intermediate Files

=======



#### Where To Put Untracked Intermediate Files

>>>>>>> theirs
```

Per @torek’s suggestion I’ve also tried with `merge.conflictstyle=diff3`, which results in different markings but essentially the same non‑conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
This is a preceding big long line, added by both sides, simplified for this post.
||||||| 87377e6
=======
This is a preceding big long line, added by both sides, simplified for this post.

>>>>>>> theirs


<<<<<<< HEAD
||||||| 87377e6
#### Where To Put Intermediate Files
=======
#### Where To Put Untracked Intermediate Files
>>>>>>> theirs

<<<<<<< HEAD
#### Where To Put Untracked Intermediate Files

This is an edited big long line which I have simplified for this post.
||||||| 87377e6
This is a big long line which I have simplified for this post.
=======
This is an edited big long line which I have simplified for this post.
>>>>>>> theirs
```

(I've changed some lines for this post, but such that non-identical lines stay non-identical.)

Careful examination shows that, between the three conflicts, `HEAD` and `theirs` above amount to the same lines.  The arrangement of the conflict markers is in this case consistent with the git-diff line order discrepancy I note later, but otherwise doesn't make any more sense.

### Reproduces In a New Repository

Here is the procedure which reproduces it, starting from scratch in an empty directory for the new repo and having `base.txt`, `ours.txt`, and `theirs.txt` on hand—more on these later:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in //bla/bla/bla/bla/bla/repo/.git/

$ cp ../test-files/base.txt .
$ mv base.txt file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m "Set base"
[main (root-commit) 30f2d24] Set base
 1 file changed, 2169 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file.txt

$ git checkout -b theirs
Switched to a new branch 'theirs'

$ rm file.txt
$ cp ../test-files/theirs.txt .
$ mv theirs.txt file.txt
$ git commit -am "Set theirs"
[theirs d5abe2c] Set theirs
 1 file changed, 81 insertions(+), 46 deletions(-)

$ git switch main
Switched to branch 'main'

$ rm file.txt
$ cp ../test-files/ours.txt .
$ mv ours.txt file.txt
$ git commit -am "Set ours"
[main a7cde04] Set ours
 1 file changed, 217 insertions(+), 49 deletions(-)

$ git merge theirs --no-ff
Auto-merging file.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

At this point there will be two places in `file.txt` with conflict markers (more when `merge.conflictstyle=diff3` is used).  The first, on line 408, is as shown at the top of the post.  The second is near the end of the file on line 2353 and has a reasonable explanation.

### Investigation

I’ve confirmed using gitk that the file mode is `100644` in all of the commits.

To try to get an explanation as to what has happened, right after the above procedure, I run these:

```
git diff :1:file.txt :2:file.txt > 1-2.txt
git diff :1:file.txt :3:file.txt > 1-3.txt
git diff :2:file.txt :3:file.txt > 2-3.txt
```

The file `2-3.txt` does not contain the string `Where To Put Untracked Intermediate Files`.

`1-2.txt` and `1-3.txt` *do* contain the string, as part of a `@@ -372,34 +389,42 @@` and `@@ -372,34 +388,42 @@` hunk, respectively.  Note that these hunks are *much* longer than the area reported as a conflict.

I open `ours.txt` and `theirs.txt` in a hex editor, carefully locate the start and end points for these hunks, and take their SHA‑1.  **The hashes are identical.**

I did find one possible clue, though:

### git-diff Line Order Discrepancy

The `a/` and `b/` files of the hunks show identical *content* between `1-2.txt` and `1-3.txt`, but the way they are *presented* in the diff output is not exactly the same.  There is a span of seven lines that are not listed in the same order, even though their orderings are functionally equivalent:

For `1-2.txt` those lines, plus the following one for clarity, are as follows:

```
 
 
-#### Where To Put Intermediate Files
 
-This is a big long line which I have simplified for this post.
+#### Where To Put Untracked Intermediate Files
+
+This is an edited big long line which I have simplified for this post.
```

For `1-3.txt` they are as follows:

```
+
 
 
-#### Where To Put Intermediate Files
+#### Where To Put Untracked Intermediate Files
 
-This is a big long line which I have simplified for this post.
+This is an edited big long line which I have simplified for this post.
```

The  `1-2.txt`, `1-3.txt` and `2-3.txt` files are identical between running with and without `merge.conflictstyle=diff3`.

### Questions

- Why are the lines ordered differently?
- **Does `git diff` promise which line ordering it will use out of the set of functionally equivalent orderings?**
- **Does `git merge` assume that if the *literal textual output* of `git diff` for a hunk is not identical, that the hunk is a conflict?**
- If it doesn’t, why was this presented as a conflict?
- How can a Git user avoid this situation?

### The Files

`base.txt`, `ours.txt`, and `theirs.txt` were in my original test closely related ~2300 line Markdown files.

I originally encounterd this conflict in an actual repository, where there had been repeated cherry-picking and merging between two branches.  I encountered it while running a `git merge --squash` with no intent to commit, to see how much the branches had converged.  At first I figured the conflict was due to the cherry-picking (which can do funny stuff like that), but the more I thought about it, the more it did not make sense, because when both sides change a file *the same way*, it’s not supposed to be a conflict.

So, after `merge` complained and before making any resolution, I ran these:

```
git show :1:the-actual-file.md > base.txt
git show :2:the-actual-file.md > ours.txt
git show :3:the-actual-file.md > theirs.txt
```

Reproducing the merge in a fresh repository was quite effective at ruling out complexities such as the cherry-picking as explanations.

`ours.txt` and `theirs.txt` have many non-conflicting changes, and I was not able to reproduce on a trivial example based just on the anomalous conflict.  However, I *was* able to reproduce on “sanitized” versions of the three files where all lines have been replaced with their SHA‑1 hex strings, which produce the same patterns of conflict and `git diff` lines as shown above.  For those interested, you can download those: [base.txt](https://pastebin.com/yNzTVsnY), [ours.txt](https://pastebin.com/sq8u0Wrs), and [theirs.txt](https://pastebin.com/K7i2FQTA).

Comment: I can't get the three files - I get a "bad gateway" error from Seattle Cloudflare, complaining about a problem at pastebin.com. But, I'd recommend setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` so that Git shows you the base file in the conflict diff. Sometimes this helps see what Git is seeing. (The actual conflicts come from using the version of the xdiff library that is included in the Git source. The text output from running `git diff` on version 1-2 and 1-3 should match since the same algorithm is being used in all cases.)

Comment: @torek  Thank you for the tips.  I've edited the question to include the output with `diff3`; it makes the conflict markers more closely follow the git-diff ordering discrepancy, but the discrepancy itself is still unexplained.  I wonder if this is sort of a bug in xdiff, causing the line ordering to be unstable depending on prior hunks.  The output is not *wrong*, but it chooses a different ordering.  That seems to make Git think it's a conflict.

Comment: @torek  And yeah, I notice downinspector.com showed some outage time on pastebin.com for a couple hours earlier today.  Sorry about that!